# jinja2 groupby choice field

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2, django-template-filters

In my Django model I have choice field

```
MY_GROUPS = [
    ('GR1', 'First Group'),
    ('GR2', 'Second Group)
]

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    group = models.CharField(choices=MY_GROUPS, max_length=3)
```

Now I use `groupby` filter to display my queryset as it is explained in [jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#groupby)

```
<ul>
{% for group in persons|groupby('group') %}
    <li>{{ group.grouper }}<ul>
    {% for person in group.list %}
        <li>{{ person.first_name }} {{ person.last_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}</ul></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But `{{ group.grouper }}` is a string which is field value: `GR1`, `GR2` . How can i get my field display name as grouper string: *First Group*, *Second Group*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`get_FOO_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method:

```
<li>{{ group.grouper.get_group_display }}<li>
```

*Note*: In templates, you don't include`()` in the name of a method.

Comment: no it doesn't work `{{ no such element: str object['get_group_display'] }}` because grouper is a string

Comment: @Goran Try only `group.get_group_display`.

Comment: group is a tuple and it contains ('str', [list of objects]) group.grouper is a first tuple element, group.list is second. It can't be done in that way and this is why I asking for help. From my opinion answer is in filter argument `groupby('group')` or to write new filter. But I was hope that someone have known solution.